# Issue with sticky option change not saving

Tags: ee4

I have a weird situation I've never seen before where turning the sticky option off in an entry and hitting save results in a 404 page in the CP. The change never saves. Here's a video of the issue: https://d.pr/v/NLgN2A

This is EE 4.3.8.

Not sure how to even begin troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar wobblies caused by more stricter server side mod_security rules being triggered. So the first place I'd look is whether saving + sticky triggers one or more mod_security rules.

Comment: So far it does seem to be a mod_security issue. Working with the host to get it resolved.